# Erro ao adicionar lista em "Checked List Box"

Tags: c#

Ao adicionar o nome duns ficheiros numa pasta a uma "Checked List Box" não aparece nada na List Box.

```
        ListBox mylist = new ListBox();

        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\scripts");
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.nse"); 
        string str = "";
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            mylist.Items.Add(file);
        } 
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(mylist);
```

Tou a usar esse codigo quando executo aparece assim:

[image]

Comment: está fazendo exatamente o que deve, pois o FileInfo é um objeto, uma classe. Se espera alguma informação do arquivo, como nome, leia a documentação para entender melhor: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8  talvez  o que queira é `mylist.Items.Add(file.Name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tenta fazer foreach na checkedlist tambem

```
   foreach (var item in mylist)
   {
       checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item);
   }
```